# PV with Arduino and 12Volt Sealed Lead Acid battery

Tags: solar-charge-controller

I have bought this solar charger (Epsolar-LS0512E): https://www.manualslib.com/manual/970886/Epsolar-Ls0512.html#manual
a 12 Volt Sealed Lead Acid battery, and I use this solar panel:

Voltage: 12V
Peak Power: 40 W 
Number of Cell: 36 Pcs 
Short Circuit Current (Isc): 2.47 A 
Open Circuit Voltage (Voc): 21.82 V 
Maximum Power Current (Imp): 2.27 A 
Maximum PowerVoltage (Vmp): 17.6 V

I want to supply a load, and by reading the solar charger manual it says to use fuses. I use special cable (4mm) for DC current from solar panel to the solar charger. My question is what fuses should I use? Is there any special fuses for PV? Should I take care of something else? It is the 1st time I use PV and I don't know how to proceed...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size the fuses to the slightly more than max of what the controller can provide.

The datasheet recommends this:

> It is recommended that no less than 2 times rated current fuse is
>   connected with battery and load.

This would give the design protection from short circuits.

The battery can support 5A so I'd use a 10A fuse. There is no rating for the load, so I would assume that 5A max for the load would be good (since that's what the battery can supply.) Use a 10A fuse there also and don't go over 5A for the load. I use car fuses (and holders) for my solar projects, they are available at auto parts stores.

[image]

Source:  https://midsummerenergy.co.uk/pdfs/ep5a.pdf

Comment: It doesn't matter that the solar panel can give Maximum Power Current (Imp): 2.27 A? So, to use 2*2.27A around 5 A??

Comment: Yeah, but the solar panel can source more volts, so the power needs to be considered. I'd go with 10A fuses

Comment: I ask for fuses + fuses cases for PV? I mean they are typical fuses I can buy from the local store or are they something advanced specially for PV? I am asking because the cables I use are special for PV panels not the ordinary... Thanks

Comment: https://www.delcity.net/store/Fuse-Holders-with-LED-Warning-Light/p_809049.h_809050.r_IF1003?mkwid=se6pKVrgO&crid=38094426869&mp_kw=&mp_mt=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIqv2w_OiP5AIVDNNkCh2tvA9BEAQYBCABEgIvOvD_BwE

Comment: Something like that, google fuse holder and find one you like

Comment: You don't need specific fuses... automotive fuses will work for the voltages you have

Comment: Can I use this: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ina219-current-sensor-breakout?view=all connected to the LOAD position of the Epsolar-LS0512E, so that I get measurements or will destroy anything? Thanks...

Comment: Someone to give an advice? Thank you